# AspectJ: two kinds of tutorials

Tags: java, aspectj

From my research I know there are two ways of using AspectJ. First is by creating `A.aj` class and second by adding annotation `@Aspect` in `A.java`.

I was looking for a good tutorial for this second kind, especially about lines like

```
@After("call(void fooMethod())")  
@Around("call(void sendAndReceive())") 
@Before("execution(String greeting(..)) && args(context)")
```

but I don't know how they are called.

Could you recommend some tutorials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This style is called *@AspectJ* to emphasize the role of annotations. Have a look at [official docs](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html) and [@AspectJ cheat sheet](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/).

Answer (score 2):

Annotation and the XML ways:

**Annotation way:**
*Minimal xml Config file:*

```
<!-- Enable autoproxy to pick up all Java files tagged as @Aspect behave like Aspects -->
<aspectj-autoproxy/>
<!-- define bean -->
<!-- Note: MyUselessAspect.java should exist and this class must be tagged as @Aspect -->
<bean id="myUselessAspect" class="...MyUselessAspect" />
```

**XML way:**
*Minimal XML configuration:*

```
<aop:config>
   <aop:aspect ref="myUselessAspect">
        <!-- this point-cut picks all methods of any return type, from any package/class with any number of Parameters -->
    <aop:before method="doSomethingBeforeMethodCall" pointcut="execution(* *.*(..))"/>
    <aop:after method="doSomethingAfterMethodCall" pointcut="execution(* *.*(..))"/>
   </aop:aspect>        
</aop:config>
<!-- No need to Annotate this java Class as @Aspect. Neither you need to define any
 Point-cuts or Advices in the Java file. The <aop:config> tag takes care of everything -->
<bean id="myUselessAspect" class="...MyUselessAspect"></bean>
```

No changes in code required.

*Pre-Req:* 
aop Namespace must exist in the XML file

Comment: Noting for the benefit of people using AspectJ, but not familiar with Spring -- Vikram's answer here is addressing how to configure aspects in Spring's configuration file.

Also, he's offering a *third* way to define an aspect -- via the XML configuration file. A similar capability is available in the AspectJ configuration file (typically called 'aop.xml'), when you're programming directly in AspectJ, rather than Spring.

Unfortunately, this isn't addressing the original question.